# Partner visa application and passport expiration

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, passport, skilled-migration

My spouse is currently in the process of applying for a partner visa, and she has been asked about the validity of my certificate of sponsorship for a skilled worker visa, which is valid for five years (01.01.2024 – 31.12.2028). However, her passport is set to expire at the end of the third year (01.01.2027). Given that the duration of the partner visa cannot be specified, with a 5-year default value, we are unsure if it's still possible to apply for the standard five-year visa, even though her passport will expire after the third year.
We anticipate to move to the UK on 01.01.2024 in case everything run smoothly. Your guidance and assistance in clarifying this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just as off-the-cuff comment: her passport is valid for another 3 years; that's plenty for all normal use cases. There's no reason to have it renewed just yet. Depending on her circumstances, she may not even be able to obtain a passport valid for a whole 5 years (I don't have any specific examples for such, but it's possible). As such, there's gotta be provisions for such circumstances. Which is usually that you get the visa in your current valid passport, and if it expires while the visa is still valid, you get a new passport _and keep the old one containing the visa as well._

Comment: Unless the visa requirements state that the passport must be valid for the entirety of the visa validity, it's probably nothing to worry about. Absolute worst case, the visa will be approved until the end of the passport's validity, and you need to apply for an extension after renewing the passport in 3 years time.